# ajax calling to a php file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to run a php file when a javascript function is called and then reload the page, it reloads the page but the php file doesn't get executed.

```
function changeR() 
{
    $.ajax({ url: 'win.php?id=1' });
    window.location.reload()
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that the PHP script isn't executed? Are you sure it isn't an error in the PHP script preventing it from running?

Comment: Ive successfully run the php file separately and it properly updates a mySQL server, when I do this, there is no change to the mySQL server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the reload once ajax call is completed. You may use the success event.

```
function changeR() 
{
  $.ajax({ url: 'win.php?id=1' ,
            success: function(data) {
                       window.location.reload()
                    }
        }); 
}
```

keep in mind that success event will be executed if the ajax call is success, if you want to execute some code no matter it is success or error, you may consider, `[complete][1]` or `done`

Alternatively you can try `window.location.href=window.location.href` instead of `window.location.reload()`

Usually folks use ajax to do **partial page updates without a page reload**. Are you sure you want to reload the entire page after your ajax call ?

**EDIT :** As per the comment

If you want to pass your php variable value via this ajax call , you can do like this

Set the value to some html element ( ex : a hidden element with id txtID )

```
//Reading the value of an html element with id `txtId` 
var val=$("#txtID").val();
$.ajax({ url: 'win.php' ,
         data: { id: val },
         success: function(data) {
                   window.location.reload()
                }
 });
```

Here you are send the value of element in a parameter named `id`. You can use firebug or fiddler to see what value is going.

More options are here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: That didn't work, is there anything you need to load before .ajax?

Comment: Is there any other script errors ? in your page ? use firebug console to see what is the error

Comment: @AaronBoswell: I had a script error (an extra closing bracket). Fixed that.try now

Comment: @AaronBoswell : Make sure you have jQuery loaded properly

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway way to pass the id=1 through as another parameter of .ajax? If so is there anyway to make the '1' be a $id, a php variable I have stored earlier in the page?

Comment: @AaronBoswell: You may keep that in a html element in the page and the n read it in your javascript and send that in your ajax call. I will update my answer with that in a minute

Comment: @AaronBoswell: I updated my answer with an example for your question

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning you perform `window.location.reload()` before the AJAX request has finished. Instead, wait until the AJAX request is done, *then* reload.

```
function changeR() 
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'win.php?id=1'
  }).done(function() {
    window.location.reload()
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure there are no errors in your `win.php` script that could prevent it from successfully executing.

Second, only perform the reload after the ajax call is completed. An easier way to accomplish this is by setting the `asyc` setting to `false`. This way the call is done synchronously, meaning it will wait for its execution to complete before continuing.

```
function changeR() 
{
    $.ajax({ url: 'win.php?id=1', async: false });
    window.location.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this into your 'changeR' function:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "win.php",
data: "id=1",
success: function(msg){
  window.location.reload();
}
});
```

Comment: `success` will be deprecated in 1.8. Instead, you should use `done`.